# Grails manual transactions with no domain classes

Tags: grails, transactions, service-layer

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here but is it possible to do manual transaction management in Grails (in groovy classes in src/groovy) without using the withTransaction method?

I don't have any domain classes in my app as I'm calling into the service layer of another Java web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service methods are transactional by default.  This is the easiest way to get transactional behavior in grails:

```
class SomethingService {
    def doSomething() {
        // transactional stuff here
    }
}
```

If you need finer grained control than this, you can start and end transactions programmatically through hibernate:

```
class CustomTransactions {
    def sessionFactory

    def doSomething() {
        def tx
        try {
            tx = sessionFactory.currentSession.beginTransaction()
            // transactional stuff here
        } finally {
            tx.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the Spring `@Transactional` annotations on service methods

Comment: If the app has no domain classes there would be no reason to have the hibernate plugin installed, so the above wouldn't even be possible

Answer (score 2):

The only way to start transactions in a Grails app are those mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18963514/2648).

> I don't have any domain classes in my app as I'm calling into the service layer of another Java web application.

Is this really a separate application or just a Java JAR that your Grails app depends on? If the former, then the transactions should be managed by the application doing the persistence.

Answer (score 2):

Above method is also correct.

You can also use `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

```
class SomethingService{

  def callingMathod(){
   /**
    * Here the call for doSomething() will
    * have its own transaction
    * and will be committed as method execution is over
    */
    doSomething()
  }


  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)      
  def doSomething() {       

       // transactional stuff here

  }
```

}